# How to create byte array from HttpPostedFile

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using an image component that has a FromBinary method. Wondering how do I convert my input stream into a byte array

```
HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[0];
byte[] buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);

ImageElement image = ImageElement.FromBinary(byteArray);
```

Comment: how are we posting the file in another .aspx page?

Comment: Doesn't this line **file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, file.ContentLength);**  fill the buffer with bytes from the input stream? Why should we use **BinaryReader.ReadBytes(...)** as mentioned by @Wolfwyrd in the answer below? Won't **ImageElement.FromBinary(buffer);** fix the problem?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Use a BinaryReader object to return a byte array from the stream like:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
```

Comment: As mentioned below by jeff, 
b.ReadBytes(file.InputStream.Length); should be 
byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
as .Length is a long whereas ReadBytes expects an int.

Comment: Remember to close the BinaryReader.

Comment: Binary reader doesn't have to be closed, because there is a using that is automaticaly closing the reader on disposal

Comment: Any idea on why this wouldn't work for a .docx file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232932/how-do-i-get-a-byte-array-from-httpinputstream-for-a-docx-file

Answer (score 28):

```
BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.InputStream.Length);
```

line 2 should be replaced with

```
byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
```

Answer (score 15):

It won't work if your file InputStream.Position is set to the end of the stream.
My additional lines:

```
Stream stream = file.InputStream;
stream.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

in your question, both buffer and byteArray seem to be byte[]. So:

```
ImageElement image = ImageElement.FromBinary(buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

before stream.copyto, you must reset stream.position to 0; then
 it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

For images if your using Web Pages v2 use the
[WebImage Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)

```
var webImage = new System.Web.Helpers.WebImage(Request.Files[0].InputStream);
byte[] imgByteArray = webImage.GetBytes();
```