# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpInputStream' to type 'System.IO.FileStream' MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have met an issue regarding the casting type from HttpInputStream to FileStream.

How I did ?

I have a `HttpPostedFileBase` object and I want to have FileStream.

I wrote:

```
public void Test(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile) {
  FileStream fileStream = (FileStream)(postedFile.InputStream); // throw exception

  FileStream anotherFileStream = postedFile.InputStream as FileStream; // null
}
```

I tried also

```
public void Test(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile) {
  Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream as Stream;

  FileStream myFile = (FileStream)stream;

}
```

But no success.

Why at `postedFile.InputStream` comes `HttpInputStream` type ?

And how could I solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Your file base InputStream (incomming stream) is HttpInputStream, not FileStream. You have to read from it and save it somewhere, maybe to your local file. For this you can use FileStream.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The stream that you get from your HTTP call is read-only sequential (non-seekable) and the FileStream is read/write seekable. You will need first to read the entire stream from the HTTP call into a byte array, then create the FileStream from that array.

Comment: An example can you provide ?

Comment: An accepted answer with no code example... Ugh

Answer (score 19):

```
public byte[] LoadUploadedFile(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
{
    var buf = new byte[uploadedFile.InputStream.Length];
    uploadedFile.InputStream.Read(buf, 0, (int)uploadedFile.InputStream.Length);
    return buf;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I used the following and it worked just fine for the same situation

```
MemoryStream streamIWant = new MemoryStream();
using (Stream mystream = (Stream)AmazonS3Service.GetObjectStream(AWSAlbumBucketName, ObjectId))                                                            
{
    mystream.CopyTo(streamIWant);
}
return streamIWant;
```

The GetObjectStream returns the same type of string mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.SaveAs` method to save the file content. `HttpInputSteam` probably because it's uploaded through http [browser]

```
 postedFile.SaveAs("Full Path to file name");
```

You can also use `CopyTo`

```
FileStream f = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.CreateNew);
postedFile.InputStream.CopyTo(f);
f.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me..

Use a BinaryReader object to return a byte array from the stream like:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream))
{
    fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
}
```

[How to create byte array from HttpPostedFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359894/how-to-create-byte-array-from-httppostedfile)

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you.
IFormFile file;

```
        if (file != null)
        {
            byte[]? image = Array.Empty<byte>();
            await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            await file!.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            image = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert to **byte array** then convert to **Stream**.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/TestReader/UploadTestReaderStudentsGrade")]
public IHttpActionResult UploadTestReaderStudentsGrade()
{
    HttpPostedFile httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
    var fileBytes = new byte[httpPostedFile.InputStream.Length];
    httpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, (int)httpPostedFile.InputStream.Length); // to byte array
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes); // to Stream

    Workbook workbook = new Workbook(stream);
    return Ok();
}
```