# ASP.Net MVC - Read File from HttpPostedFileBase without save

Tags: file, c#-4.0, file-io, asp.net-mvc-2, stream

I am uploading the file by using file upload option. And i am directly send this file from View to Controller in POST method like,

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Page2(FormCollection objCollection)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
    }
```

Assume, i am uploading a notepad file. How do i read this file & append this text to string builder,, without save that file....

I'm aware about after `SaveAs` this file, we can read this file. But How do i read this file from `HttpPostedFileBase` without save?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This can be done using **httpPostedFileBase** class returns the **HttpInputStreamObject** as per specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You should convert the stream into byte array and then you can read file content

Please refer following link

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx**]

Hope this helps

UPDATE :

> The stream that you get from your HTTP call is read-only sequential
>   (non-seekable) and the FileStream is read/write seekable. You will
>   need first to read the entire stream from the HTTP call into a byte
>   array, then create the FileStream from that array.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13119863/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-web-httpinputstream-to-type-system-io-fi)

```
// Read bytes from http input stream
BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);

string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: P.S. b.ReadBytes() wants an int but file.InputStream.Length is a long

Comment: but file.InputStream.ContentLength is an int

Comment: Tiny modification, ContentLength is on file.ContentLength, not file.InputStream.ContentLength

Answer (score 46):

An alternative is to use StreamReader.

```
public void FunctionName(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string result = new StreamReader(file.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: this will empty out the stream making file.Length = 0

Comment: agreed, but in a lot of cases this is OK.

Comment: Althought +1, You aren't disposing of an `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 9):

A slight change to Thangamani Palanisamy answer, which allows the Binary reader to be disposed and corrects the input length issue in his comments.

```
string result = string.Empty;

using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
{
  byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
  result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(binData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

byte[] data; using(Stream inputStream=file.InputStream) { MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream; if (memoryStream == null) { memoryStream = new MemoryStream(); inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream); } data = memoryStream.ToArray(); }