# Convert HttpPostedBase to format usable with File.ReadAllLines()

Tags: c#

I want to be able to use the code block below, but instead of using a saved file I have an uploaded file as a `HttpPostedFileBase`. How to I convert that to an equivalent format where I can use the contents of the uploaded file with the code below without saving it first?

```
  List<DailyValues> values = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Josh\\Sample.csv")
                                               .Skip(1)
                                               .Select(v => DailyValues.FromCsv(v))
                                               .ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC - Read File from HttpPostedFileBase without save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030034/asp-net-mvc-read-file-from-httppostedfilebase-without-save)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The best way is to read the data as a [`Stream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) from the [`InputStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx) property on that object.