# What should i use for an HttpPostedFileBase Read Type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, httpfilecollection

I have a form where the user submits some details and a file of any kind, now since the file uploaded is of type HttpPostedFileBase, how can i arrange the reader from GetString in order to **read the File Name of the uploaded file.** Thanks

**Error in Code**

[image]

**Properties**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.Net MVC - Read File from HttpPostedFileBase without save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030034/asp-net-mvc-read-file-from-httppostedfilebase-without-save)

Comment: Yes, i saw it but still confused on how to implement it

Comment: My problem is about what should i write instead of `reader.GetString(3)` I found this line which should return the File Name -->  `string pathName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);`

Answer (score 0):

Why not to check file extention by something like:
f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf('.')+1, 3));

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you meant.. i need the File Name

Comment: `f.Path = reader.GetString(f.Substring(f.LastIndexOf('.') + 1, 3));` -- Like this?