# How to convert submitted image to stream?

Tags: asp.net, image

I have posted a form with an image.
And receiving that in my controller

```
var image=Request.Files["hiddenUploadButton"];
```

Now I want to convert my image to Stream. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var stream  = Request.Files["hiddenUploadButton"].InputStream;
```

Please see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx).

Perhaps you want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359894/how-to-create-byte-array-from-httppostedfile)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if you want to save file try following code snippet

 HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];

    //check file was submitted
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", fname)));
    }
```

How TO Convert to stream,

```
     HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];
var FileLen = file .ContentLength;
   byte[] input = new byte[FileLen];
  System.IO.Stream MyStream;
   // Initialize the stream.
   MyStream = file .InputStream;

   // Read the file into the byte array.
   MyStream.Read(input, 0, FileLen);
```