# C# Getting User Role always empty. Multiple ways tried, none work

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, active-directory, web-config

i created a WebApplication which contains a `menu`. My goal is that a certain User-Group called `"mgaLVTSekretariat"` can't access the menu.

I am using ASP.Net, C# and EF6.

I tried these methods:

**Opt. 1:**

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "mgaLVTSekretariat"))
{
     //my code to block the menu
}
```

**Opt. 2:**

```
if (User.IsInRole("mgaLVTSekretariat"))
{
     //my code to block the menu
}
```

**Opt. 3:**

```
if (RolePrincipal.Current.IsInRole("mgaLVTAdministration"))
{
     //my code to block the menu
}
```

When i execute my Program, the `if-statement` is never `true`. When i read out the value, the role is empty. In every Opt. i tried.

I am afraid that my mistake is in my Web.Config. So here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  Weitere Informationen zum Konfigurieren der ASP.NET-Anwendung finden Sie unter
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <configSections>

    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="Gmos.Foundation.CommonResourceSettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="infragistics.web" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler,System, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <infragistics.web styleSetName="Nautilus"/>
  <nlog>
    <extensions>
      <add assembly="NLog.Extended"/>
    </extensions>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" levels="Info,Warn,Error,Fatal" writeTo="fileAll"/>
      <logger name="*" levels="Warn,Error,Fatal" writeTo="fileWarning"/>
    </rules>
  </nlog>
  <applicationSettings>

    <Gmos.Foundation.CommonResourceSettings>
      <setting name="GlobalResourcePath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>\\pfsprog01\programs$\Webservices\__AppSettings\</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LocalResourcePath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>./</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="UseLocalResource" serializeAs="String">
        <value>false</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultLogoLink" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DefaultLogoTooltip" serializeAs="String">
        <value/>
      </setting>
    </Gmos.Foundation.CommonResourceSettings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    //Connectionstrings
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>

    <!-- System -->
    <add key="ApplicationID" value="HTX"/>
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="Lernende Administration"/>
    <add key="ApplicationNameKurz" value="Lernende Administration"/>
    <add key="VersionID" value="1.0.0"/>
    <add key="Configuration" value="E"/>
    <add key="PfadWebApi" value="http://localhost:24751/"/>
    <add key="mailAbsenderDefault" value="halbtax@gmos.ch"/>
    <add key="pfadMailTemplateHalbtax" value="C:\Projekte\Gmos.Halbtax\Gmos.Halbtax.Admin.Client.WebGui\MailTemplates"></add>
    <!--<add key="pfadMailTemplateHalbtax" value="\\gmos.ch\WebServerFarm$\Farm_A\Entwicklung\Content\api.halbtaxbestellung.gmos.ch\MailTemplates"></add>-->

    <!-- E=Entwicklung; T=Test; Q=Qualitaet; P=Produktion -->
  </appSettings>

  <!--
    Eine Beschreibung der Änderungen von 'web.config' finden Sie unter 'http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367'.

    Die folgenden Attribute können für die <httpRuntime>-Kennung festgelegt werden.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
        <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
        <!--<add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />-->
      </modules>

      <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit"
           path="*."
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"
           modules="IsapiModule"
           scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll"
           preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64"
           responseBufferLimit="0" />

        <remove name="WebDAV"/>
        <!--<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>-->
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>


      </handlers>


    </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DELETE" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>

    <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider" description="Default SiteMap provider." type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider " siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <machineKey validationKey="A11233429FC0BB0107BC4593F963125F3D6057132F0DF614870B56F9A9F4C729AF3F0F692071893F98760EEE93CF812B34EA9AFD7D33C475536A41DFCC8BEA16" decryptionKey="603A95C7BC9CE0CF81BA5E7A8D5CE68C1245E033E041F46980665E465DE50580" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx"/>
    <pages theme="GMOS_blau" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="act" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.5.7.0725, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
        <add tagPrefix="gmos" namespace="Gmos.WebUserControls" assembly="Gmos.WebUserControls"/>
        <add tagPrefix="ig" namespace="Infragistics.Web.UI.LayoutControls"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="mgaLVTAdministration, mgaLVTSekretariat"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="Loadbalancer.aspx" allowOverride="true">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true"/>
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="false"></windowsAuthentication>
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

The Menu contains 3 different sites to open:

- StammdatenHalbtax.aspx
- StammdatenStatus.aspx
- Default.aspx

I tried to block these 3 Sites in my Web.Config too:

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow roles="mgaLVTAdministration, mgaLVTSekretariat"/>
            <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
       </location>
<location path="StammdatenHalbtax.aspx">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow roles="mgaLVTSekretariat"/>
            <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>
  <location path="StammdatenStatus.aspx">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow roles="mgaLVTSekretariat"/>
            <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>
```

Both Ways dont work. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359894/how-to-create-byte-array-from-httppostedfile) could help you.

Comment: Thank you but how do i implement it, into my project? @diiN_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `BinaryReader` to convert the `PostedFile` to a `byte` array:

```
HttpPostedFile file = FileUploadPassfoto.PostedFile;
using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
{
    lehrling.passfoto = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359894/how-to-create-byte-array-from-httppostedfile)

Comment: @AlessandroMinneci Yes, you add the code to your if statement.

Comment: what do i do when the lehrling.passfoto has the value " " (null) @diiN_