# Error: Cannot access a closed file when converting imagefile into bytes

Tags: c#

[image]Whenever converting the imagefile into bytes we *got an error* like

> cannot access a closed file

Please help me in order to overcome this

```
private byte[] ConvertToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);

    imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);

    return imageBytes;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030034/asp-net-mvc-read-file-from-httppostedfilebase-without-save

Comment: Which line do you get this error on? `BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);`?

Comment: imageBytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength); in this line i got error.

Comment: In another related question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805858/1689226) there has been comments to try to set the `Position` of the `InputStream` object. You can try that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BinaryReader` object to return a byte array from the stream like:

```
byte[] fileData = null;
var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Request.Files[0].InputStream);
fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(Request.Files[0].ContentLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help:

```
try
{
    using (var bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file.InputStream))
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
             bitmap.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
             return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
finally
{
    postedFile.InputStream.Position = 0;
}
```